# How do you identify the codec of a .mp4 video file using OpenCV 3.4.14 in Xcode?

Tags: c++, xcode, opencv, ffmpeg, codec

I tried

```
cv::VideoCapture cap( argv[1] );
unsigned f = (unsigned)cap.get( cv::CAP_PROP_FOURCC );
cout << "f: " << f << endl;
```

but the output of f was 0.
The codec of the video file is H.264.

Comment: related: https://forum.opencv.org/t/how-do-you-identify-the-codec-of-a-mp4-video-file-in-xcode/4453

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your type conversion is **unsigned** based. It would be better to use kind of:

```
int f = static_cast<int>(cap.get(cv::CAP_PROP_FOURCC));
```

After that according to the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.2/d7/d9e/tutorial_video_write.html), you should make a transformation from int to char via bitwise operators.

```
    cv::VideoCapture cap("/ur/video/dir/video.mp4");

    int ex = static_cast<int>(cap.get(cv::CAP_PROP_FOURCC));     // Get Codec Type- Int form
    char EXT[] = {(char)(ex & 0XFF) , (char)((ex & 0XFF00) >> 8),(char)((ex & 0XFF0000) >> 16),(char)((ex & 0XFF000000) >> 24), 0};

    std::cout<<ex<<std::endl;
```

Comment: I tried your code and I got ex = 0 and EXT had no output.  I got my code from Example 8-1 on p. 195 of "Learning OpenCV 3" book by Adrian Kaehler & Gary Bradski.